# Can the integral $ \int_0^R\quad J_{m-n}(a r)J_m(b r) dr$ be explicitly represented in a closed form?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions, bessel-functions

Doe the following definite integral have an explicit representation in terms of a Bessel functions or a generalized hypergeometric function ${}_pF_q$?
$$
\int_0^R\quad J_{m-n}(a r)J_m(b r) dr, \quad \quad (*)
$$
where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$.

The following related integral does indeed have a representation in terms of ${}_pF_q$:
$$
\int \quad J_{m-n}(r)J_m(r) dr
$$
This can be seen in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20besselj%28m-n%2Cr%29*besselj%28m%2Cr%29%20dr).

So can the integral $(*)$ also be explicitly represented in terms of a Bessel functions or a generalized hypergeometric function? If I try it in Wolfram Alpha for  the case of $a=2, b=1$, it returns 'no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions'. So the prospects aren't good. But I thought I'd ask here just to be sure.

Edit: Modified to to also ask about closed-form representation in terms of Bessel functions.

Comment: the definite integral $\int_0^\infty$ does have a closed form expression in terms of hypergeometric functions

Answer (score 2):

Carlo's comment for the definite integral $\int_0^
\infty$. From Maple
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty }\,{{\rm J}_{m-n}\left(ar\right)}\;{{\rm J}_{n}\left(br
\right)}\,{\rm d}r={\frac {{a}^{-1-n}{b}^{n}\Gamma \left( m/2+1/2
 \right) }{\Gamma \left( 1/2-n+m/2 \right) \Gamma \left( 1+n \right) }
\;{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}\!\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{1+2n-m}{2};\;1+n;
\;{\frac {{b}^{2}}{{a}^{2}}}\right)}}
$$

But the definite integral $\int_0^1$ Maple does not evaluate unless $a=b$.

Comment: That's a pity, $\int_{0}^{1}\,{{\rm J}_{m-n}\left(ar\right)}\;{{\rm J}_{n}\left(br
\right)}\,r {\rm d}r$ would also be of use but I imagine it also can't be evaluated explicitly when the upper limit is finite.

Comment: $\int_0^R$ is just a change of variables from $\int_0^1$  with different $a,b$.